# pyzmq: how do you filter at publisher side

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

On http://zguide.zeromq.org/ it says "Pub-sub filtering is now done at the publisher side instead of subscriber side. This improves performance significantly in many pub-sub use cases. You can mix v3.2 and v2.1/v2.2 publishers and subscribers safely."

And I am following examples on http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html and filtering happens on subscriber side.

How do I filter on publisher side?

Note: I have pyzmq-14.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Implementation is transparent, where ZMQ capability allows

User-defined code does not intervene into this. The ZMQ internal capability is a deciding factor. In either case, the **`SUB`**-side sets it's subscription preference(s) via **`.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, ... )`**

The implementation model of v2.x / v3.2+ decides, on the lower, capability-based level, whether the **`PUB`**-side has the know-how on how to filter on it's side, or whether the v2.x simply pumps all messages down all the `.bind()` / **`.connect()`**-ed transport-classes and relies on the SUB-side ( be it v2.x  or v3.2+ ) to filter out those that do not match the setup list-of-SUB-side-subscriptions

```
print zmq.pyzmq_version()            # display the localhost ZMQ-capability-model
```

N.b.:

From ZeroMQ v3.x, filtering happens at the publisher side when using a connected protocol (**`tcp:`** or **`ipc:`**). Using the `epgm://` protocol, filtering happens at the subscriber side. In ZeroMQ v2.x, all filtering happened at the subscriber side.

Comment: ah gotcha. print zmq.pyzmq_version() printed 14.3.1.